# How to get value from node? SQL Server XML dml

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

```
@x xml:'
<a number="1">
 <b>1</b>
</a>'
```

I want use `query()` to get value (can't use `value()`)

```
@x.query('string(/a[1]/b[1])')
```

is ok.

```
@x.query('string(/a[@number="1"]/b)')
```

throws an error.

Do you have any solution? I want use `[@number="1"]` to get value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
@x.query('string( (/a[@number="1"]/b)[1])')
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases one wants to read more than one value from a given node. You can use a combination of `.nodes()` (very related to `.query()`, but returning a derived table) and `.query()` or `.value()` like here:

```
DECLARE @x xml=
N'<a number="1">
 <b>1</b>
</a>';

SELECT MyA.value(N'(b/text())[1]','int') AS ReadTheValue
      ,MyA.query(N'b') QueryTheValue
FROM @x.nodes(N'/a[@number="1"]') AS A(MyA);
```

You can pass in the search value as a variable like here:

```
DECLARE @SearchNumber INT=1;
SELECT MyA.value(N'(b/text())[1]','int') AS ReadTheValue
      ,MyA.query(N'b') QueryTheValue
FROM @x.nodes(N'/a[@number=sql:variable("@SearchNumber")]') AS A(MyA);
```

If you need nothing else then the value through `.query()` go with the solution provided by Serkan Aslan. You were just missing to ensure the inner experession to be singleton.

But I must admit, that I have no idea, why one should need this...